# Oracle JAVA IDEs freeze

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, netbeans

I experience a freeze since few months.

I'm using Phpstorm and since june I has to downgrade java (oracle, phpstorm can't work with openJdk) jdk from 8 to 6 to avoid a freeze when the IDE is indexing files.
The bug came back in Jully and I could fix it temporaly with java 7.
On september the bug came back but this time I couldn't get rid of it. I tried every java version, this time I called phpstorm's customer support for help but after 2 month re installing ubuntu, tacking CPU snapshot, sending callstacks and testing the dev version of IDE with or without plugins, fresh projects and so on ... I still have no luck and the bug continue to forbid me to use ubuntu for work wich is a serious problem.

My first tought on september was that phpstorm or one of the plugin I used had a new bug with my system, but when I tried with netbean or eclipse, the exact same problem occured on file indexing !

So the problem is something else, and with all the tests and search I could make I feel it's a java issue.

Now i'm really decided to fix this as I really need my ubuntu desktop to work seriously, what information do you need ?

I use ubuntu 15.10, but the bug was present on 15.04.
Is that possible that my hardware is involved ?

When the freeze happend I can't use any other application, if I try to open a web page even in the same tab, it won't load until ~30 minutes. The console can't provide any invormation like ps aux and the only way to kill phpstorm is to get process id before it start indexing to kill it in a single line.

On jdk 7 I can't change my virtual desktop either.
On Windows it works perfectly.
On my laptop with the same setup (ubuntu and softwares) I don't experience the problem.

Is someone have an idea ?

Comment: Does the workaround described at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1510009 help?

Comment: Nope, it' about openJdk